# Analytical solution to Poisson’s equation 1D

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

[image]

I need some help in finding u(x) analytically where equation and the boundary conditions are satisfied

Comment: What have you tried ? This is a simple ordinary equation (no need of partial derivative).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything wrong with integrating twice?

$$u(x) = -\frac{x^2}{2} + A x + B$$

$$u(0) = 1 \implies B = 1$$
$$u(1) = 2 \implies -\frac12 + A + B = 2 \implies A=\frac{3}{2}$$

Comment: thank you , yes I have some problems because I have not use these math skills 6 years ago